# How to randomly selected column from two tables in database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want to make reading toefl test. i have two tables named 'id_reading' and 'soal_reading'. id_reading table contain id and text. soal_reading contain id, question, option a b c d and answer. so i want to display data from that tables. but i want to display randomly all column in soal_reading tables except id column. i try but it wont random. please help.

```
<?php 
        include "conection.php";

    $query = mysql_query("
    SELECT id_reading.id
         , text
         , id_reading.text
         , soal_reading.pertanyaan
         , a
         , b
         , c
         , d
         , jawaban 
      from id_reading
          , soal_reading 
      where id_reading.id = soal_reading.id
      ");
           if ($query) {
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                   echo "
                     <tr>
                       <td>".$row['id']."</td>
                       <td>".$row['text']."</td>";
                       $q = mysql_query("SELECT * from soal_reading order by rand()");
                       if ($q) {
                        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                          echo "
                                <td>".$r['pertanyaan']."</td>
                                <td>".$r['a']."</td>
                                <td>".$r['b']."</td>
                                <td>".$r['c']."</td>
                                <td>".$r['d']."</td>
                                <td>".$r['jawaban']."</td>
                                <td>
                                 <a href=\"edit_reading.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Edit</a> |
                                 <a href=\"hapus_reading.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                          </tr>";
                           }
                        }
                   }
           }
?>
```

Comment: Now would be a really good time to stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API.

Comment: Also, see normalization. Normalize your schema And then, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Finally, id_reading is a really strange name for a table.

Answer (score 0):

Your query set in a random way questions but not fields in the question. So if you have 3 questions for example Q1, Q2,Q3 they are ordered in a random way, not the fields.

I suggest you to put your `$r['a'] .... $r['d']` into an array and then extract a number from `0 to count($array)` to get a possible answer and remove that element from the array. Do that until all possible answers are extracted. `(count($array)==0)`.

In summary, your query provides you random order for your questions and in PHP you give a random order to your fields.

For some code, please comment.
Bye